# DB Connections dying in Spring Boot + Postgres Aurora RDS + Kubernetes

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a Kubernetes Spring Boot Service that is accessing an AWS Aurora Postgres RDS DB. The service has been up for 7 days but now drops its connections and won't reconnect unless we restart the service instances.

We have each instance configured to have 10 db connections, and typically we see 3 instances (ie replicas) for a total of 30 connections. Now they stay up and are active and then start dropping about 1/3 of their connections over about a 1.5-2 hour timeframe until they get to zero and stay there.

We saw this behavior previously when the service was not configured properly to have the connections reconnect. We made those changes and, as I mentioned, the services have been up for about a week.

Here are the env variables:

```
spring.application.name=<application-name> 
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.initial-size=5
spring.datasource.max-active=10
spring.datasource.max-idle=5
spring.datasource.min-evictable-idle-time-millis=60000
spring.datasource.min-idle=1
spring.datasource.password=<pwd>
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=5000
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://<dburl>
spring.datasource.username=<username>
spring.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.mail.host=<url>
spring.profiles.active=master
spring_mail_password=
spring_mail_username=
```

Anyone have any clues what could be causing these connections to be dying and not reconnecting?

Comment: 1. Don't use a valiation query, JDBC 4 has better ways of validating a connection, 2. without knowing which Spring Boot version you are using it is impossible to tell as part of those properties might not even be applicable.

Comment: Spring boot version is 2.3.1. I have seen comments elsewhere regarding the removal of the validation-query. I believe the JDBC 4 connection validation is through code?

Comment: JDBC4 validation is automatically done by HikariCP (the default connection pool).

Comment: This is still happening, even after removing the validation query. It seems to be on a cycle of every 15 days now